# XPath expression where self, parent and child all have same value for an attribute?

Tags: xpath

I am looking for an XPath expression that selects the `him`s that have child, `kid`'s, and parent, `gramps`'s with `first`'s that are all the same.  In the example below that would only be `Bill`.

```
<root>

<gramps first="Bill">
   <him first="Bill">
      <kid first="Bill"></kid>
   </him>
</gramps>
<gramps first="Tom">
   <him first="Al">
      <kid first="Al"></kid>
   </him>
</gramps>
<gramps first="Bob">
   <him first="Bob">
      <kid first="Sam"></kid>
   </him>
</gramps>

</root>
```

Comment: I've slightly updated my answer. Please check it again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
//gramps/him[@first=kid/@first and @first=../@first]
```

Demo here - http://www.xpathtester.com/obj/6f8c493b-368c-47bb-a1f9-45191375f177